# to get folders from directory between the dates entered in two textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have made this code

Now I want to get folders from directory between the dates entered in two textboxes

```
protected void GenerateLogs()
{
    if (DdlProcess.SelectedValue == "099")
    {
        string logfolder = @"E:\ANA\Projects\Lime\Logs";
        string[] alldirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(logfolder);//get directory
        if (alldirectories.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < alldirectories.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(alldirectories[i]);//get files inside folder
                if (allfiles.Length > 0)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < allfiles.Length; j++)
                    {
                        FileInfo objfileinfo = new FileInfo(allfiles[j]);
                        string filename =       Path.GetFileName(objfileinfo.FullName);
                        if(filename.Contains("_"))
                        {
                            var filedata = File.ReadAllLines(allfiles[j]);//get file name containing "_"
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //no (_)
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //no files in date folder
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //no files in logs folder
        }
    }
```

I have made this code

Now I want to get folders from directory between the dates entered in two textboxes.Please help to do this

Comment: What is the role of dates? On creation/ modification? It is not clear

Comment: At time of file creation

Comment: The date/times are in DirectoryInfo (not Directory).

Comment: "I want to get folders from directory between the dates " && "At time of file creation" what happens if half of the files in the folders are created outside the date interval? Please post the code where you access the `TextBox` text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter the files you are gonna iterate through, you can use `System.IO`'s `FileInfo` class instead if `File`. Then you filter the files by their `CreationDate` property:

```
DateTime yourstartDate = new DateTime();
DateTime yourEndDate = new DateTime();
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("any_directory");
List<FileInfo> fis = di.GetFiles().Where(x => x.CreationTime >= yourstartDate && x.CreationTime <= yourEndDate).ToList()
// your can iterate this list now with for or foreach
```

### Example

I will create  `.txt` files and store the timestamp before and after creating the second file.

```
File.Create("C:/temp/file1.txt");
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
File.Create("C:/temp/file2.txt");
DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
foreach (FileInfo fi in new DirectoryInfo("C:/temp").GetFiles().Where(x => x.CreationTime >= start && x.CreationTime <= end))
{
    // will only get file2.txt
}
```